# Trying to find SQLSysClrTypes_64.msi and SQLSysClrTypes_32.msi downloads

Tags: sql

I am trying to find SQLSysClrTypes_64.msi and SQLSysClrTypes_32.msi downloads.I want to embed them as part of my custom installer.Can you please guide me where do I find the installers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files you are looking for can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55992

in the SQL Server Feature Pack. This particular one is for the 2017 version.

Comment: Thank you so much :). I could download them from the link.